# Why does std::result_of not work with lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda

I managed to reduce my case to the following simplest piece of code:

```
#include <type_traits>

auto call(const auto& f) -> typename std::result_of<decltype(f)()>::type
{
  return f();
}

int main()
{
  return call([] { return 0; });
}
```

Neither gcc-4.9.2 and gcc-5.0.0 compile!

Both think that "call" should be returning a lambda function!
The don't figure out that "call" returns an int.

Is this a bug in the compiler or is my c++ off?
Many thanks.

Comment: Thats not the way you call `std::result_of`, it should be `typename std::result_of<decltype(f)()>::type`. Or even simpler you could just write `decltype(f())`.

Comment: @Paul That looks about right, and would be better if posted as an answer. Are you planning on doing so?

Comment: In gcc 4.9, `auto` is allowed as a parameter. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html)

Comment: @Paul It's not implemented as documented, though. It's known to be buggy.

Comment: @hvd Right now, [the buggy implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64969) actually ignores the trailing return type and transforms the placeholder `auto` into `T` too.

Comment: @T.C. Yikes, I completely missed that. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, corrected to typename std::result_of<decltype(f)()>::type

Comment: @T.C. The error messages are consistent with what you are saying. Is consistent with gcc implementation of auto-parameters being buggy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code's not valid C++ because function parameter types cannot be `auto`, this syntax has been proposed for Concepts Lite and may become part of the language in the future.

[`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) needs a call expression from which it will deduce the return type.

Fixing both of these, your code becomes

```
template<typename F>
auto call(F const& f) -> typename std::result_of<decltype(f)()>::type
//                    or typename std::result_of<F()>::type
{
  return f();
}
```

Or you could just use

```
template<typename F>
auto call(F const& f) -> decltype(f())
{
  return f();
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77743e573bc1e049)

---

I think your original code should compile if you fix the `result_of` expression, but it doesn't on gcc-4.9 or 5.0; maybe this is a bug with the gcc extension that allows parameter types to be `auto`

```
// This fails to compile
auto call3(const auto& f) -> typename std::result_of<decltype(f)()>::type
{
  return f();
}
```

Comment: Please see @T.C.'s discussion in the post's thread. He points out that auto parameters are allowed in gcc, but the buggy implementation may be messing up this case.

Comment: @user2059893 That fits perfectly with the error message about *<lambda type>* not being convertible to `int`

Comment: Right you are. It seems we may have to wait for later compiler version (5.0.0 won't compile it), or simply avoid non-standard auto-parameters. Many thanks you for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Thats not the way you call `std::result_of`, it should be:

```
auto call(const auto& f) -> typename std::result_of<decltype(f)()>::type
{
  return f();
}
```

Or even simpler you could just write:

```
auto call(const auto& f) -> decltype(f())
{
  return f();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right. This was a lesser problem, the bigger problem seems to be with gcc's buggy implementation of auto-parameters. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score -3):

**FUNCTION PARAMETER AS 'auto' is supported since c++14 / c++1y** 
< MORE EASY SOLUTION >
Here the problem is both the auto will be considered of same type [DECIDED BY LANGUAGE STANDARD - **HATERS WILL SAY BUG**].

Solution :

1) '->' and return type is not at all required since c++14, as the funcion call has only one return statement.

2) To overcome same type of all the auto's policy [auto:1, auto:2,...], LETS GO VARIADIC

3) Explicitly check for single parameter or not.

```
#include <initializer_list>

auto call(const auto&... f)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(f)==1,"Exactly 1 argument should be provided");
    return std::begin({f...})[0]();   // black magic : to call first arg of singleton pack
}


int main()
{
    return call([] {return 0;});
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.
Note : Tested in TDM GCC 4.9.2, cygwin gcc 5.0

*SHOULD BE COMPILED WITH -std=c++14 or -std=c++1y*